# Laravel - How to start artisan automatically only once?

Tags: laravel

If I have some artisan command and want to fire an event only once, is it possible run only if HTTP started first time?

Note: There are while-loop so it should be maybe good run as shell sh script (not via browser), like exec() command without return data.

I found solution using posix_getpgrp() and compare with cache::forever var. If is not same than call event and remove forever cache. Forever cache remember even if restart apache service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution. Use event listener and check is stored data into session then if not set, call script once, store cache data that is called. If you restart apache or want to force call script change your cache data.

What you need is to combine:

[Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache)

[Events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events)

Answer (score 0):

You can call artisan commands from your app using

```
Artisan::call('your-command',array());
```

For example to create schema I would have route /create-schema then in the method I would have something like this

```
public function createSchema()
{
    Artisan::call('migrate:install');
    Artisan::call('migrate');
}
```

Comment: But, how to execute if only once when first time app is load? Put inside to start/ directory?